# Graph of $\sin(x)$ along the line $y=x$

Tags: calculus, analysis, trigonometry, coordinate-systems

I want the equation of $\sin(x)$ which has the line $y=x$ as its axis. Basically, I want the $\frac\pi4$ rotation of the curve $y=\sin(x)$.

I already attempted differentiating the curve and adding $\frac\pi4$ by using the angle between two lines formula, i.e., $\displaystyle \tan\theta=\frac{m_1-m_2}{1-m_1m_2}$. And consequently integrating the result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As parametric curve?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Consider the parametrization of your curve:

$$\mathbf{s}(t) = (t, \sin(t)), \quad t \in \mathbb{R},$$

then, the transformation given by:

$$ \mathbf{p}(t;\theta) = M \, \mathbf{s}^T(t), \quad  M = \left(\begin{array}{cc} \sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta} \\ -\cos{\theta} & \sin\theta \end{array}\right),$$

applies a clockwise rotation of angle $\theta$ to $\mathbf{s}(t)$.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The curve is given implicitly by the equation
$$
\frac{-x+y}{\sqrt2}=\sin\frac{x+y}{\sqrt2}
.
$$
You won't be able to solve for $y$ as an explicit function of $x$.

([Wolfram Alpha plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%28-x%2By%29%2Fsqrt%282%29+%3D+sin%28%28x%2By%29%2Fsqrt%282%29%29%2C+y%3Dx).)

Comment: Can you please tell me how you arrived at the answer? I'm a noob at this

Comment: Start with the curve $v=\sin u$, then rotate the coordinate system by 45 degrees through the change of variables $u=(x+y)/\sqrt{2}$, $v=(-x+y)/\sqrt{2}$. (To explain how linear changes of variables work would be too much of a detour here; see a linear algebra book for that. It's probably explained elsewhere on this site as well.)